# Donde Conseguir WSDL'S para hacer pruebas

Tags: webservice, wsdl

Buenas tardes estoy buscando algun sitio en donde encontrar web services para hacer pruebas, algun sitio con WSDL'S expuestos para hacer pruebas.

Comment: Ahi tienes uno de ejemplo: https://www.crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.Demo.CLS?WSDL=1. La descripción del servicio: https://www.crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.Demo.cls

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Que codigo se puede añadir para preguntar sitios donde pueda conseguir ejemplos de Wsdl's ??